# ¿Cómo puedo restaurar una base de datos Postgres con php?

Tags: php, postgresql

Vi una pregunta en este sitio que muestra como restaurar una bd mysql en php, pero me haría falta una para postgres.

Comment: puedes agregar lo que haz hecho?

Comment: ¿A que te refieres con "restaurarla"? edita tu pregunta haciendo click [aqui](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/110984/edit)

Comment: amigo restaurar es por ejemplo alguien por error borra la base de datos y quiero que a nivel de la aplicacion web el pueda restaurar su base de datos sin entrar al gestor d bd

Comment: http://www.emagister.com/uploads_courses/Comunidad_Emagister_35361_MySQL_PHP.pdf   deberías investigar mas por tu cuenta y si tienes algún problema en especifico si venir a preguntar ya teniendo algo Saludos!!

Answer (score 1):

## Restaurar backups de PostgreSQL

Puedes utilizar por consola en ***postgresql*** la siguiente instrucción:

```
pg_restore -i -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres -d mibase -v "/home/damian/backups/mibase.backup"
```

Nos pedirá la contraseña del usuario que vamos a usar.

Los parámetros que podemos pasarle al comando, nada mejor que darse una vuelta por la [documentación oficial](https://www.postgresql.org/), ya que hay algún que otro detalle que estaría bueno conocer (y además, porque es buena práctica leer la documentación oficial).

Sobre los parámetros del ejemplo, paso a detallarlos.

- **i** le indica que ignore la versión (entre el comando y la base de datos).
- **h** localhost es el host de nuestro PostgreSql.
- **p** 5432 es la indicación del puerto donde corre el servicio.
- **U** postgres especifica que se usará el usuario postgres para la operación.
- **d** mibase es para que realize la restauración sobre una base de datos en particular, en este caso mibase.
- **v** ejecutará el comando en modo verbose (así podremos ir viendo la salida de cada paso del proceso).
  `/home/damian/backups/mibase.backup` es el archivo que usaremos como backup y que queremos ingresar.